# How to secure an authorization server without a public client or BFF pattern with KeyCloak?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I currently got an OAuth2 Resource Server configured - similar to [Ch4mpy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619830/ch4mp) set-up on [GitHub](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server). As for the OIDC Provider I'm using KeyCloak. Everything works so far - I can easily send my requests to the Authorization Server (KeyCloak) via e.g. Postman, get JWT and authenticate myself to access the resources I'm allowed according to the RBAC that I configured.

Now I'm heavily struggling with connecting my front-end applications with my back-end. In our system we got multiple apps (both B2B and B2C of nature - so different access points) and a variety of other front-end interfaces (like websites).

According to most documentations I now should either

1. use **public clients** for all interfaces that aren't able to store client secrets.
2. *[or]* use a **BFF pattern** for each front-end application.

Both aren't really feasible as the first suggestion would compromise security and the latter would require multiple servers to handle the communication.

Thus I've been thinking towards implementing a back-end that would get sufficient privileges (i.e. a confidential client) that sits in between all front-end applications and the authorization server. Unluckily, I wasn't able to find proper resources because with that matter comes new issues:

- How to secure the back-end application? (I.e. Make sure that no unauthorized calls can access it)
- How does the authentication flow work when a back-end server is in between these instances?
- How to integrate further IDPs (like Google Sign-In or Apple Sign-In) in this architecture?

All in all, **how to "secure" the authorization server when not using a public client or a 1-on-1 BFF client for all front-end applications?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the "authorization server" is Keycloak. You don't provide Spring Security configuration for it. To prevent brute force, log login attempts, etc, refer to Keycloak documentation. Same for adding federated identity sources (like "social" login from Google or Facebook, but also a corporate LDAP or whatever).

A "backend in front of all the front-ends" is a BFF. BFF is configured as a confidential client and secures it's requests from front-ends with sessions. If you want to log authorization_code flow initiations, there, refer to the underlying middleware documentation (like `spring-cloud-gateway` if using it as BFF)

But I already explained that in the tutorials you are referring to...

Comment: But securing the BFF, e.g. by logging incoming requests (IP, device ID and so forth) and trying to prevent for example brute force attacks? Furthermore, isn't a BFF needed for both web and mobile (separate - as e.g. web would work with Cookies in comparison to mobile)?

Comment: Furthermore, in your [BFF tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) no RBAC mappings (e.g. @PreAuthorize) like in the Servlet Resource Server are defined? I thought the BFF serves as a client in between Resource Server and e.g. my web front-end. Why is the Resource Server missing the authentication tags?

Comment: Like I'd assume the Resource Server doesn't change and and the authentication on there remains the same? The BFF only serves as a Relay / replacement to the Public Client pattern by exchanging a cookie to the needed token? Why do the Resource Server in your main tutorial (and the one from your spring addons) differ to the one mentioned in your BFF tutorial? @ch4mp

Comment: In the resource server used in BFF, I only need `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` which is automatically applied as the `/greetings` route is not listed in `permit-all` properties, but RBAC is enabled (security conf is decorated with `@EnableMethodSecurity` and roles are mapped according to application properties). As stated in READMEs, `servlet-resource-server` and `reactive-resource-server` (as well as their client equivalents) use only Boot "official" starters, when the BFF use enhanced starters of mine (more beans configured from properties, including authorities mapper)

Comment: But I still don’t get how your ‘servlet-resource-server’ tutorial and the ‘BFF pattern’ work together? The one you mentioned in your tutorial doesn’t include the ‘PreAuthorize’? How can I still specify what roles are allowed at each endpoint / keep the resource server similar and at the same time introduce a BFF for my front-ends? @ch4mp

Comment: As I wrote just before, I don't need any authority check in this resource server (checking that the request is authorized is enough there). But as I also wrote, RBAC is enabled (authorities are mapped from JWT and `@EnableMethodSecurity` is there) => add `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('NICE')")` to the controller and you'll see. The BFF pattern works exactly as wrote in the README: the spring-cloud-gateway `TokenRelay` filter replaces incoming session cookie with the access token it stores in the associated session before forwarding the request to the resource server.

Comment: Ok. So one can set-up his resource server IDENTICAL to your `servlet-resource-server` tutorial and the BFF and TokenRelay properly works? From a security standpoint, should the BFF implement further security measurements such as rate limiting and so forth? The BFF would just be for web versions, correct? If an app (front-end) were to call the back-end it should access the resource server directly as a public client? Or should it also call the BFF?

Comment: I accepted your answer as it seems to fulfill the question thoroughly. Though I'd appreciate some clarifying words in regard to my last messages if that's doable :) As mentioned there are 2-3 unanswered aspects - or at least I wasn't able to grasp them from the context of your tutorial and answer.

Comment: The resource server doesn't care what kind of client queries it, so yes, you can configure the resource server(s) with just the Spring Boot "offical" starters behind the gateway, your conf Wil just be much more verbose and less flexible than in the BFF tutorials.

Comment: Mobile apps configured as public client are exposed to about the same vulnerabilities than web ones: any malicious app can pretend to be your mobile app to get tokens (there is no client secret than only a server app can keep) and you must be very careful with how tokens are stored by the lib / framework: are you sure that another app on the device can't steal access, or worth refresh, tokens from the storage? So, it would probably better that the mobile apps are secured with session + CSRF protection too (but it is rarely an easy task).

Comment: If you had read the BFF tutorial README carefully enough, you'd have noticed that there are two different routes to the greetings API, with and without the TokenRelay filter, so it is possible to query this API through the gateway with requests authorized with a session cookie or an access token (just use the right route)

Comment: Last, for things that are not related to Spring Security, use another tool. Regarding rate limiting the requests to the API, spring-cloud-gateway doc seems pretty adapted. For the requests to Keycloak, as wrote earlier, refer to Keycloak doc. If the feature each proposes is are not enough, put a Middleware...